# back to top after a script run

Tags: javascript

I embedded a polldady poll in my page, but after the user clicks the vote button I want to scroll the page back to the top.

This is the JavaScript embed code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6061322.js"></script>
   <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6061322/">أختار مرشحك للرئاسة</a></noscript>
```

Comment: can you post the html surrounding that button

Answer (score 1):

```
scroll(0,0)
```

should to the trick.

Comment: It's pretty standard JavaScript. Should work in every browser that supports JavaScript. Just have it execute when the user clicks the vote button.

Comment: i want it to back to top automatically after click vote bottom

Comment: You can't magically poof some JavaScript to make the browser scroll up without doing something to the button itself. If you don't have direct access to the HTML of the vote button, you can run some JavaScript after the page has been loaded and locate the button by its ID.